# Django authorizing request even if permissions.AllowAny is set

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am working on a Django REST framework project. I am using JWT authentication, in my login view i have set permission classes to AllowAny. '

```
@decorators.api_view(["POST"])
@decorators.permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])
def login(request):
    print("REQUEST in login = ", request)
    try:
        username = request.data['username']
        print(username)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except Exception as e:
        return response.Response({'username': "User doesn't exist"} , status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    try: 
        password = request.data["password"]
        print(password)
    except: 
        return response.Response({"password": "Password not valid"}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        res = {
            "message": "Logged in successfully",
            "refresh": str(refresh),
            "access": str(refresh.access_token),
        }        
        return response.Response(res, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return response.Response({"password": "Password not valid"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When i send a normal request everything works as expected.

[image: Picture of a login request sent with no Authorization header]

But when i set the Authorization header to empty string (or null both have same problem)

Authorization: null or ''

[image: We can see that Django suddenly started authorizing the request]

The reason why Authorization is set to null is because of axios in React. It looks for access token in local storage. If not present it sets it to null.

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 60000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      ? 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      : null,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

I have set the default authentication to JWT in django.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

I can think of removing the Authorization header and setting new axiosInstance while logging in. But this will make the code less cleaner. Please suggest any fix for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom subclass of `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication` and handle the value of the header any way you like.

```
import re
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication

class CustomJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def get_header(self, request):
        header = super().get_header(request)
        # value is usually "Bearer <token>"
        if header is None:
            return header

        if not re.match("Bearer \S+", header)
            return None
        
        return header
```

We are doing this because `JWTAuthentication` will only skip checking when `JWTAuthentication.get_header()` returns `None` else it will keep going.

So providing values like `null`, `undefined`, or an empty string in axios will send it's string representation (e.g. `null` will be "null") and `JWTAuthentication` will take it as it is.

---

Another solution outside django but in axios is to not include it through `tranformRequest`.

```
const apiAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL.href,
  transformRequest: [
    function (data, headers) {
      const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
      if (accessToken) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      } else {
        delete headers.Authorization
      }

      return JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  ],
  headers: defaultApiHeaders,
});
```